# Python Flask + Threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading, caching, flask

I would like to make a function, that runs in background and updates a variable every X minutes for my website.

Basically what I need is to cache some json data and update it every X minutes.

What would be the best way to do it? I tried "threading" and it seems to work, but when I run it with Flask, it runs itself 2 times every time.

Comment: Don't use threading. Create two endpoints, one for display, one for the data. Use javascript to periodically update the display page with the data.

Comment: No no, I don't actually want to display the data to the user. I want other functions to make use of the always-fresh data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you may use [Celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/celery/) to create delayed tasks to update your data.

But I don't think, that update variable directly is a good idea. So, store your data in cache or database. It depends on the frequency of how you use and update data.

Comment: I would like to store the data somewhere, so that I don't have to request it from another server every time I load the page. Updating doesn't have to be frequent, but obtaining the data.. well, almost every time I load the page.

Comment: @RayZorPL store it in redis or a database.